# Selecting top of word document using VBA

Tags: excel, runtime-error, ms-word, vba

I am using excel VBA to populate data onto a word template from an excel spreadsheet. The problem I am having is selecting the top of the word document so the information goes into the right spot.

I have tried using `Selection.HomeKey wd:=Story` and `Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdScreen, count:=1` both with no success as I am consistently getting

> `runtime error 4120`

Comment: @pnuts excel was a recommended tag and word vba since the code I was trying to figure out was in Word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\StartOfDoc").Select
```

It makes use of a pre-defined, implicit bookmark to take you to the beginning of the document.

I just tested in Word 2016 and it works.